# Adjectival noun - singular or plural or both?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, grammatical-number

If I intend to use a noun as an adjective, can I use the noun both in plural and singular form?

e.g. "noun modifier", "Bacon Batch", "A news reporter", "Sports center", "email address"

My feeling is that adjectival noun are usually singular. How come some of the above examples that are in plural? What if, says, "school uniform" or "Company law", If i really want to emphasise "schools" or "companies", could I use the plural form as an adjective?

Why some of the nouns can be used as plural while the other not?

Comment: The problem here is that these noun modifiers are almost always use in a generic sense, e.g., "school lunch program".  Only in special cases do they refer to something more specific, e.g., "Harvard alumni".  If you want to talk about something that pertains to more than one associated other thing, you will most likely need to revert to the possessive case: "the schools' cheerleader squads were in hot competition with one another."  This is basically a matter of usage, and listeners likely won't get it if you try to break the rule.  If you don't believe this, try it out on some test readers.

Comment: "news" and "sports" are not plural. They are **mass nouns**.       http://www.google.com/search?q=mass+noun&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: in depends on what sense we mean "plural." They are syntactically singular, but morphologically plural.

Comment: Wouldn't you use the plural of the noun? School uniforms instead of schools uniform? The confusion with the possessive would likely cause confusion.

Comment: But it's easy to find real attributive plurals in common use, like *enemies list*.  The language is changing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A mice problem" vs. "a mouse problem"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem), [server replication or servers replication](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263226/server-replication-or-servers-replication/263277#263277), [Plural modifying noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236843/plural-modifying-noun/236861#236861) ...

Answer (score 0):

> - My feeling is that adjectival noun are usually singular

Right on

> - How come some of the above examples that are in plural?

Have you heard of "news" in singular?

> - If i really want to emphasise "schools" or "companies", could I use the plural form as an adjective?

Possible, but **very** reluctantly, check Google Books for precedents

Comment: I understand that it would be quite unusual, at least to my instinct, to use some nouns such as "schools" as adjective. However, is it possible to discern the reasons why some nouns cannot be used as such?
As you mentioned, the reason for some extreme examples such as news may be more obvious, as we never use news in such way. But how about the majority of the "less extreme" nouns?

Comment: In English, a singular noun used as premodifier can represent a __multitude__ already: school uniforms can represent uniforms from __several schools__, if you know how to write your context.

Comment: I am not sure about your comment here. My feeling is that it depends on the article rather than the noun itself
so "the School uniform" mean a particular school
while the School uniforms may mean "A school has more than one uniform" or "uniforms which students wear, generally speaking"
So the noun itself does not seem to convey any real sense of multitude to me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/the-companies-money-or-the-companies-money that's a possible alternative

Comment: Go to Google Books and dig a bit yourself to see various cases.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I am relatively new to here so may I ask one peripheral thing - actually what do you mean by saying "go to google books"?

Answer (score 0):

> Some singular uncountable nouns end in –s. They have no plural forms.
> Examples are: news, billiards, draughts, measles etc. (from [this website](http://www.englishgrammar.org/nouns-exist-singular-plural-form/))

So in your example, that is not actually a plural.
Furthermore, there is no reason why a noun adjunct (adjectival noun) couldn't be plural. It's a noun after all, not an adjective(it just behaves like one).

> Noun adjuncts were traditionally mostly singular (e.g. "trouser
> press") except when there were lexical restrictions (e.g. "arms
> race"), but there is a recent trend towards more use of plural ones (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct))

But it's not up to you to decide whether you want to use the plural or not.
College uniform is correct, but colleges uniform / colleges uniforms are not.

Basically what all this means is that noun adjuncts should in fact always be singular, but there are some exceptions; just like the exceptions with irregular plurals and irregular nouns.