# Point, points, or points' distribution in space?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, saxon-genitive

Let's say there are 10 points on a plane, and I'd like to describe their distribution as homogeneous. Which of the following is correct?

> 1. The **point** distribution is homogeneous.
> 2. The **points** distribution is homogeneous.
> 3. The **points'** distribution is homogeneous.

I have heard the 1st a lot. I tend to use the 3rd as it sounds more logical to me to maintain both the plurality of the points and to use a genitive, but I have the feeling the 2nd is correct when I rephrase it using 'people' instead of 'points'. In that case the choice would be between

> 1. The **person** distribution is homogeneous.
> 2. The **people** distribution is homogeneous.
> 3. The **people's** distribution is homogeneous.

What is the correct way to say it? 
Thank you.

**Edit:** it's been pointed out that this question is in matter the same as ["A mice problem" vs. "a mouse problem"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem). But I believe my doubt goes beyond the choice between single and plural attributive noun.

Comment: I like this question. The first set seems simple; _point_ is using the noun attributively, _points'_ is a correctly used plural genitive, and _points_ looks a bit off. But your _people_ example behaves differently.

Comment: The 'singular or plural attributive noun' question is answered at ["A mice problem" vs. "a mouse problem"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem) (in a nutshell, singular attributives are more common, but plural ones are available on logical grounds). The 'attributive noun vs genitive structure' query is answered in another question.

Comment: As a mathematician I would read the 1st and 3rd statements at least somewhat differently. The 1st statement would indicate that i have an actual distribution (in the meaning of the word as used in probability) for one or more points. I might not even have any points currently I might just know that whenever they might be used the distribution according to which they appear (are observed) will be homogenous. In the 3rd sentence to me it sounds a lot more as if I actually have some set of points (probably in some n-dimensional space) which are homogeneously distributed (in that same space).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have the feeling there a difference with the mouse/mice case you cite. To use another example, let's take a strange table with 10 legs. We'd all speak about the _table leg_ but how would you speak about their spacing? Would you still consider correct to say _leg spacing_ or you'd have to switch to plural with genitive, _legs' spacing_?

Comment: @DRF There's where I come too. But still let's assume a sociologist is analysing the behaviour of 10 people in a room. Then they might speak about their distribution in space. As odd as it can sound... If a person and a point are equivalent for the hypothetical sociologist, then my question remains valid

Comment: If you want a ruling on which are grammatically acceptable, I'd say that there is no rule in English disallowing any of the six. If you want to know which sound most natural, I personally would go with A2 and B4 (The distribution of the people is homogeneous). But  the answer to the linked question ('My best recommendation would be to use whichever phrasing sounds best in the particular context') also applies here, and really, we're getting into 'should be closed as answers will merely be opinions' territory.

Comment: @araucaria  The { [A: What's on television?

B: Nothing.] 'Which of Grice's maxims is being violated?} question has been moved to Linguistics. Dominik Lukes gives some great analysis there, but includes  "This brief discourse could simultaneously be said to violate:

[a] No maxim at all. The conversation was fully informative for both parties (as I have witnessed in real life many times)." While I agree that this is the better approach, I believe that Grice started from the bald definition that all figurative language violated the 'maxim of truthfulness' no matter how clear the interpretation

Comment: was. Would you mind asking him if this is true, and whether there are different versions of Grice's maxims nowadays? (I'm not able to do so.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure you posted the last two comments on the right thread?

Comment: @raggot I can't access the right thread (thanks to the niceties of the transfer mechanism). Notice that this 'non-comment' is addressed to araucaria.

Answer (score 2):

How about "distribution of points" for clarity?

Comment: A good suggestion, but it does not really answer the question.

Comment: I'm hoping it gets at the intention behind the question, which seems to be "How do I say this in a way that is clearly grammatically correct, which cannot be criticized on grammatical grounds?"

Comment: @WBT Thanks, but Drew is right. The origin of my question is a dispute between colleagues. And the stakes are high :)

Comment: Well, maybe it'll be helpful for somebody else who's doing comes across this question after a search with the intention I noted.

Comment: @WBT: The proper way to offer it as helpful info that is not an answer is to **make it a comment** to the question. Yes, comments can be helpful. They just are not answers to the question.