# Systems Manager -- noun as adjective

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

As an ESL teacher, I am currently teaching the topic on nouns as adjectives. Some examples are **shoe** shop, **boat**-race, **apple** tree, etc. One of the rules of nouns as adjectives that I have learnt is that when nouns are used an adjectives, they are usually in singular form. Some cases that seem like exceptions but aren't really, are **news** reporter and **sales** manager, as we all know that news and sales are really singular nouns ending with an s.

But for these other job titles, Systems Analyst and Systems Manager, could anyone give me a clear explanation on why we use the plural form **systems** instead of its singular form before I resort to telling them it's an exception?

Comment: Addressed at [A 'mice problem' vs a 'mouse problem](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem/171726#171726) and [Is it correct to say I write children books ... not possessive case?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364).

Comment: Understand that when nouns modify other nouns, they do not become adjectives. They remain nouns. You should not call these "nouns as adjectives" because it is deceptive.