# What is the grammatically correct: "Languages Services" or "Language Services"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, british-english, attributive-nouns

Is "Languages Services" correct for when you offer multiple services for multiple languages? Or should it still be "Language Services"?
Why?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Hello, X. You need to (1) check whether this type of question has been asked here before (it has); (2) if this test is passed (it isn't here), add research you have done yourself (eg Google searches).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A mice problem" vs. "a mouse problem"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem) and other questions dealing with plural-form attributive nouns, including [Woman or women as a-stand-in for the adjective female?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-for-the-adjective-female/161619#161619).

Answer (score 0):

1. ***Language Services*** - a service providing assistance (teachers, interpreters, translators, proof reading, style guidance...) with a particular language (e.g. English, or Chinese, or Arabic ...) rather than for multiple languages.  *Language* being singular suggests this (although it does not preclude that services may be for more than one language).
2. ***Languages Service*** - a service providing assistance with several different languages.

***Languages Services*** - Although not technically wrong (so far as I can tell, see also ["A mice problem" vs. "a mouse problem"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem)) this does not sound right to me.

Comment: I would think that language is something universal, a general term. Thus wouldn't use it plural.

Comment: @Grizzly - foreign languages!

Comment: that is totally fine. I understand multiple languages from there. But if I hear language only, for me it is universal something that doesn't require plural s. I think it is just me, how I see language.

Comment: @Grizzly - It's clear common usage is *Language Services* - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Language+Services%2CLanguage+Service%2CLanguages+Service%2CLanguages+Services&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLanguage%20Services%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLanguage%20Service%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLanguages%20Service%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLanguages%20Services%3B%2Cc0