# "combat sports lesson" (sports with s) or "combat sport lesson"?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

what is the right way to say?

"combat sports lesson" (sports with s) or "combat sport lesson"?

It should not mean a specific style of combat sport like wrestling or karate.

It should mean combat sport in general.

Thank you.

Comment: In North America, TV announcers say * NOW SPORTS* whereas in English-speaking parts of the other three continents where I have lived, it's *NOW SPORT*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are attributive nouns plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural) See also [a mice problem vs a mouse problem](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/a-mice-problem-vs-a-mouse-problem), and recognise that there is often no definitive answer hereabouts; checking Gooogle Ngrams and internet usages is often the best way to ascertain idiomaticity in particular cases.

Comment: Thank you very much Ronald and Edwin. Hope you will help me with the follow-up-question - see below please.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely prefer **sports**. You would say “sports lesson“ as a general term, combat just specifies it to a certain field of sports (still in general). Since you want to express the general term, the better word is **sports**. If you would **only** speak of wrestling, the word **sport** would be used.

For example:

The general term:

> I really enjoy the (combat) **sports** lessons.

The specific term:

> Wrestling is my favorite combat **sport**.

Comment: Hello HP. May I refer you to this comment from @ tchrist: We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.

Comment: Do you want me to delete the answer? I'm sorry it doesn't meet the criteria, but I figured that this 'answer' would have been too long for a comment. Also, I think the question itself refers to something that is partly opinion based. Am I wrong there?

Comment: Opinions are often wrong and ELU (and OP) requires authoritative answers rather than punditry. You could add some stats from raw Google searches and Google Ngrams – not conclusive, but far less subjective. Though really, on ELU, such reasonable research is expected to accompany the question.

Comment: Hello E.A. and H.P., thank you very much. I like your answers very much! Im looking for an option with substantial base to construct a structure of words which doesn't feels bad for the opinion of the majority of reader. You made a great job! Hope you will help me with the follow-up question, too (see below, please).

Answer (score 0):

FOLLOW-UP-QUESTION

The words combat sport(s) & lesson(s) are not part of a sentence!

They should be a headline!

"Combat sport" is what it is about. And "lesson(s)" should be an addition just to make it more descriptive.

Im free to style it, for example:

a) Combat sport - lesson

b) Combat sport (lesson)

c) Combat sports - lesson

d) Combat sports (lesson)

e) Combat sport - lessons

f) Combat sport (lessons)

g) Combat sports - lessons

h) Combat sports (lessons)

1. Are these options gramatically correct?
2. And what is your feeling, opinion about these options. Which one would you prefer spontaneously without thinking?

Comment: I found that you can probably use both, they are both grammatical. 'Sports' is preferably used in the US, 'sport' in British English. Spontaneously, I would still prefer 'combat sports lessons'. Besides that, the hyphen looks a bit odd to me, but maybe this is just me. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you H.P. Are you in general more familiar with US english or British english?

Comment: I am definitely no expert in either one of them, but I would say American English, as I surround myself with mostly American stuff (music, movies, news,...) and learn from it.